# Backbone.js Events wont Fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have been trying for the last few days to get events to fire, so I stripped the app back to basics and I'm still running the problem where firing events will not work.

Everything else in backbone works great apart from this I hope someone can help.

Currently in my view

```
    define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/SpecificationModel',
  'collections/SpecificationCollection',
  'text!templates/specification/specificationlisttemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, specModel, specCollection, specTemplate){

  var Specifications = Backbone.View.extend({

      events: {
            'click a.btn': 'showAlert'
      },
      showAlert: function() {
            alert('fired');
      },
      initialize:function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            var self = this;
            this.collection = new specCollection();
            this.collection.fetch({
              success: function () {
                self.render();
              }
            });
        },

        render: function(){
          var data = {
            specs: this.collection.toJSON()
          };
          var compiledTemplate = _.template(specTemplate);
          $("#backBoneContent").html(compiledTemplate(data));
        }
      });

  return Specifications;
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="backBoneContent">
    //

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#review/1" class="btn">View </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#review/2" class="btn>View </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
   //
   </div>
```

Comment: How do you instantiate your view?

Comment: What do you mean, I bind my html to $("#backBoneContent")

Comment: Something like  `new Specifications(...)`

Comment: Oh right in my router, I will link you pastebin

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wU8M049D

Comment: From your code, you should set `el` for the view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify any `el` to which Backbone should attach the view<sup>1</sup>, thus the events can't be delegated and the events never fire.

As a rule of thumb, never use directly a jQuery object in your view, use [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) or [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) and pass the container as an option to your view:

In your router,

```
var specsView = new SpecsView({el: "#backBoneContent"});
```

In your view

```
render: function() {
    ...
    this.$el.html(compiledTemplate(data));
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Note that accessing `$("#backBoneContent")` has no special meaning in for Backbone, it's just a jQuery object.

Comment: Thank-you, I was close but no cigar :) I will accept soon as clock reaches 5 minutes.